# Calling a JS library in my Content Script - WebExtension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, syntax-highlighting, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a **webextension**, firefox but I think this applies to chrome as well, which executes (`chrome.tabs.executeScript`, called in the `background.js`) a content script on a `browserAction.onClicked` listener. This content script more or less creates an dom *element* on the current tab using some data from the page. This element has some **html code** inside and everything works swimmingly -- except I'm trying to get it's *syntax highlighted*. Now, there are a few different libraries which do this (Prism, HighlightjS, Rainbow, and some others).

The general idea with these libraries, if I'm not mistaken, is to call `colorify`, or some such function, on a `<code>` div and then using a **css** sheet *highlight* that syntax. I have tried a number of things to get both/either the relevant **js** or **css** scripts to be sourced onto a page:

such as, `executeScript` along with the content script in my `background.js`, in this case I'd include this script inside my `background` declaration in the `manifest.json`:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
  file: "/content_scripts/highlight.pack.js"
});
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
  file: "/content_scripts/my_content_script.js"
});
```

I've also tried loading it in via the **manifest** (which is also what I've tried with the **css**):

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content_scripts/highlight.pack.js"],
    "css" : ["content_scripts/solarized-light.css"]
  }
],
```

In either case I've then tried a few things to load this/these libraries into the content script which is doing the aforementioned main lifting (creating a div on the page):

I've tried simply letting the library, such as `Prism` do it's thing (by putting my `<code>` inside a `<pre>` and giving it the appropriate `className`, or even calling it manually from the content script:

```
var Prism = { highlightElement: function() {} };
window.addEventListener('load', () => {var Prism = window.Prism; });
```

Or more simply

```
Rainbow.color(div, function() {
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
// or 
window.Rainbow.color( //... etc
```

or simpliest of all:

```
window.hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
// or
hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
```

Part of my problem, and why I am discouraged, is that when I open the inspector/debugger sometimes I'll see the **js** file *sourced*, but I won't be able to call any functions from the **console**. And, moreover, the **css** files never seem to get sourced.

So the basics of what I'm looking to do are to call a 3rd party javascript library inside my *content script* and source a css sheet from my **webextension** into the `activeTab` my content script is modifying.

1. How should I include the libraries?
2. How can I debug the content script, to test how to use the libraries?

Comment: _"Part of my problem, and why I am discouraged, is that when I open the inspector/debugger sometimes I'll see the js file sourced, but I won't be able to call any functions from the console."_ By default you get the page context, which is [separate from extension context](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment). There's a drop-down above the console (defaults to "top") to switch it. See if that helps debug.

Comment: In the console, I see a drop down, but not with "top", instead Errors and Warnings. But in anycase I've made sure everything's selected. I'll keep poking around the debugger/inspector/and other tools firefox offers, and thanks for the link

Comment: For current version of Chrome, it looks like [this](http://imgur.com/AeeCedG)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot it was about Firefox.

Comment: no worries! That link is nice, but it's mostly about sending messages back and forth between scripts. Does this apply also to calling other content scripts? I'm unable to call anything in the console, even though I see the highlight.js there...

Comment: Ok i see something similiar to the picture you uploaded, basically a moz-extension source highlight.pack.js -- so it's sourced, but I can't figure how to call the library (using it's hljs object) from the console (or from the content script for that matter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124651/discussion-between-nevermore-and-xan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So @Xan helped be get around to debugging this using a **breakpoint** inside the content script inside the Firefox console.

1. I ran the background script, which executes the content script
2. My **manifest** includes the css necessary for syntax highlighting. I could also include the js file here, but instead I add it to the `background.js` as something I execute (`chrome.tabs.executeScript()`) So that way it's only run if I need it. (Otherwise it'll run all the time.
3. In the inspector **Debugging** tab I put a breakpoint inside my main content script
4. Inside the breakpoint I was able to use the console to call the syntax highlighting library as if it's a global variable.

From there I was able to test how to call the script etc. I eventually called `highlightjs`'s `hljs` object *without* a `window` specifier. Just calling, inside my content script:

```
hljs.highlightBlock(myDiv);
```